# error in dr Racket problem. unbound identifier in mymeber

Tags: racket

trying to do a dr racket problem to tell if a number is apart of list. getting errors

```
#lang racket
(mymember (x, l))
if l=?null
then "false"
if x==car(l)
then "true"
mymember(x,l)


mymember 2' (1,3,4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Racket uses prefix notation. This makes commas unnecessary. First, some syntax:

**How to define a function?**

**`(`** **`define`** **`(`** *`name`* *`variable1`* *`variable2`* **`)`** *`body`* **`)`**

Where `name` is the name of the function, and the `variable`s are the parameters. Which are followed by the `body` expression.

Example:

```
; Number -> Number
; converts from fahrenheit to celsius.

(define (f2c f)
  (* 5/9 (- f 32)))
```

**How to call a function?**

**`(`** `name` *`expression1`* *`expression2`* **`)`**

`name` is the name of the function and `expression1` and `expression2` are its arguments.

Example:

```
(sqr 3)
;; == 9
```

Similarly, to check if two values are equal: `(equal? x y)`

**How to use the if expressions?**

**`(`** **`if`** *`question-expression`* *`then-answer-expression`* *`else-answer-expression`* **`)`**

If the value of the question-expression is not false, the `if` evaluates the `then-answer-expression`, otherwise it evaluates the `else-answer-expression`.

Example:

```
;; Number -> Number
;; reciprocate all non-zero x, otherwise return 0.
(define (inverse-of-x x)
  (if (= x 0) 0 (/ 1 x)))
```

... and so on. Read the [Racket Guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/index.html) for the essentials on syntax, semantics and datatypes in the language.

---

Fixing all the syntax still leads to one error: an infinite loop. That is because the recursive call doesn't call `cdr` on the list. So the recursive call is made on the same list (not a shorter list) forever. Wrapping a `cdr` and fixing the syntax leads to a correct function.

```
#lang racket

; [X] [List-of X] -> "true" U "false"
; is x an element of l?
(define (mymember x l)
  (if (equal? l null)
      "false"
      (if (equal? x (car l))
          "true"
          (mymember x (cdr l)))))


(mymember 2 '())          ; = false
(mymember 2 '(1 3 4 5 6)) ; = false
(mymember 2 '(1 3 2 5 6)) ; = true
```